# Flash freezes frequently on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash, windows-10, microsoft-edge

This happens in Chrome, Firefox and even Microsoft Edge. Never had the problem before I upgraded to Windows 10 on my Lenovo Edge E520 from Windows 7.

The problem is not consistent, but frequent. Today I haven't got it working at all, even after multiple restarts.

I've tried a number of different pages with different types of Flash apps. Chat app, YouTube, audio samples on a music page etc.

Any suggestions to how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Try updating your adobe flash player, and clear the cache in all browsers and check the flash plugin in each browser.

Comment: Flash Player is automatically updated in Chrome, so check. Cache cleared - didn't help.

To be honest, this pattern is too obvious for me. There's something systemwide going on here, not specific to any browser. There may be some graphics driver incompatibility with Windows 10, or a pure Win 10 + Flash bug going on.

But that is anyway outside my field of knowledge.

Comment: You are wrong, flash player is not updated in chrome, and since it is affecting all other browsers, I know that it's windows 10 so it would have an updated flash, then just once go to their website and check the flash player version there.

Comment: Okay. I can't go there, though. Flash freezes when I try to go to https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/. EDIT: I disabled Flash and tried again. The version number listed on that page is the same as in chrome:plugins. It is already updated. I run 32-bit Windows 10, if that helps, btw.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Currently, Flash is working. I will get back with a picture when the problem reappears.

Comment: Did you do something or it started working correctly itself.

Comment: Just a restart; no changes. However, booted my computer up once again now, and now the error reappears. I have gotten a print screen, but imgur doesn't work because of Flash right now.

Comment: Okay, here's a picture: [link](http://imgur.com/TF5n0Dz) The spinning loading icon continues spinning indefinitely, and I'm prompted to quit Flash because it's frozen, or wait, as a pop-up, in addition to the yellow notification bar in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simply reinstalling Windows 10 from scratch with 64 bit instead of 32 bit.

We concluded that something must have gotten corrupted during direct upgrade from Windows 7. Now Flash works perfectly.

There's also a significant performance boost with less freezing.

EDIT: But no, the problem has suddenly started reappearing out of the blue. I will now try Probitas UK's solution, and see if it works for me as well. I'll get back to you guys.

EDIT2: Everything's kay-okay now. Guess there must have been an update fixing the issue, because I didn't do anything after the last update.

Answer (score 2):

I have been battling with this exact same problem for a while on my Lenovo E530.

I have now resolved it.

For me it was a problem with my audio drivers.  The lenovo used the Conexant 20671 HD audio drivers.  I uninstalled them rebooted and Windows found it's own device drivers and installed them.

Hey Presto! Edge, Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome all started working again.  Hopefully this can help some of you out there experiencing a similar system wide problem.

I would also check Video drivers is the audio ones don't fix it for you.

Good Luck